# PHP designer 8 Syntax Highlighing

Tags: php, syntax, designer, highlighting, phpdesigner

I tried to change the error highlighter in PHP Designer 8 in preferences but nothing changed.
I want to change the annoying red background in error highlighter.
[image]

Comment: I do not use PHP Designer, but it looks in your screenshot like you've  set the foreground to a dark red colour, could that be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to:

*Tools -> Preferences -> Debugger -> Syntax Check*

And disable the checkbox "highlight warnings and errors"

In this page you'll also find all the other options regarding "syntax check for PHP"